# Prevent bypassing SelectedIndexChanged in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling, selectedindexchanged

I was surprised, that `SelectedIndexChanged` on a `ComboBox` with `ComboBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList` can be bypassed by changing the shown value to another one.

Here are steps to reproduce the case:

- Create a `Form` with a `ComboBox` with `ComboBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`and some other control, which can get the focus (e.g. `TextBox`)
- Attach an event handler for `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` and let
  say do reset the selected index of `ComboBox` there always to 0 for
  only first entry could be selected.
- Fill `ComboBox.Items` with e.g. integers from 1 to 5.
- Start the application and open drop down list
- Click any entry except the first and hold left mouse button down(no LMBUp
  must be triggered)
- Press `TAB` key holding the left mouse button down
- **Clicked value is shown in the `ComboBox` and no
  `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` being triggered.**

What would be your offer to prevent this undesirable behavior. `Tab` key must not be suppressed and `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` must be triggered on change.

Some code for copy-paste:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(1);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(2);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(3);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(4);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(5);
    
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed the event is ignored: the selection is modified and the focus passes to the next control. Any breakpoint is ignored.

Comment: @OlivierRogier selection changed or text changed? Can we verify current selected index? Can we test if `selectedItemchanged` fired or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinForms ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged not firing when typing few chars followed by Alt+Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759579/winforms-combobox-selectedindexchanged-not-firing-when-typing-few-chars-followed) and [ComboBox SelectionChangeCommitted event doesn't work with AutoComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488659/combobox-selectionchangecommitted-event-doesnt-work-with-autocomplete)

Comment: @T.S. The Selected index is changed, not only the text.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thank you for the links, there the `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` be discussed, but I got a solution with derived control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it with derived control:

```
class ModifiedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private object _lastSelectedItem = null;

    protected override void OnDropDownClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(SelectedItem != _lastSelectedItem)
        {
            OnSelectedIndexChanged(new EventArgs());
        }
        base.OnDropDownClosed(e);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        _lastSelectedItem = SelectedItem;
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear “why” you want this odd behavior from a `ComboBox`; however, it appears you did not look a little closer at the `ComboBox` events.

It is true what you describe... When the user presses the Tab key “while” still holding the mouse button on a selection in the combo box… then the `ComboBoxes` `SelectedIndexChanged` event does NOT fire since the control is still IN the process of “selecting” a different index.

However, the `ComboBoxes` `Validating` and `Leave` events DO fire in the above situation. Instead of creating another control for this, wiring up the combo boxes `Validating` or `Leave` event will fix what you describe. Something like…

The current `SelectedIndexChanged` for normal situations…

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

Then, using the `ComboBoxes` `Leave` event for the “special” case when the user Tabs out of the combo box.

```
private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean with _"odd behavior from ComboBox"_ resetting the index or that `SelectedInexChanged` event be fired on selection is changed? If the first, then context is preventing entry selection, which is used as kind of separator in the dropdownlist. For me it's clear bug in the control.

Comment: @Rekshino … _”…then context is preventing entry selection, which is used as kind of separator in the dropdownlist.”_ … ? … if the context is to “prevent entry selection”, then, why not simply disable the combo box? What context creates this particular situation? In addition, I am not sure if I agree with your term a “bug”. What is the combo box supposed to do? It is in the middle of “selecting” a new index and is kicked out “before” it can complete the operation and fire its events.

Comment: Call it a “bug” if you like, however, the designers HAD to make a decision on what to do if the combo box lost focus WHILE it was in the middle of a selection change. They chose to keep the “currently” selected value. Not a bug, just a simple decision when the control loses focus during its operation. The designers had to pick one value over another. What you are calling a “bug” is more of a user problem. Use the control properly and problem solved.

Comment: Only one/several entries must be disabled not complete combobox. "simple decision" - not to fire an event if change is occur?? And it doesn't matter whether the control has focus for firing the `SelectedIndexChanged` if selected index is changed, e.g. programmatically.

Comment: @Rekshino…  _”Only one/several entries must be disabled not complete combobox.”_ … then filter the combo box items to show only the items you want when the user clicks on the combo box.

Comment: _”"simple decision" - not to fire an event if change is occur??”_ … ? … from your description to re-create this… the “selection” is NEVER made. The user Tabs away before this is completed.

Comment: _”And it doesn't matter whether the control has focus for firing the SelectedIndexChanged if selected index is changed, e.g. programmatically”_ …? … but this is NOT what you describe. The user is doing this Tab away action before they have “selected” a combo box value. Changing the index programmatically has nothing to do with what you describe.

Comment: I am just saying that what you describe as a “bug” is more along the lines of what the designers decided to do when this happens. They MUST decide something and unfortunately it is different than what you want. If the user chooses to Tab away “before” making a selection in the combo box, then the user is not completing this action. What you are calling a bug, is simply the USER not using the control properly.

Comment: I do not want to argue this and if you want to call it a bug, then so be it.