# Data is lost in some databinded objects like textbox, combobox, etc in VB.net application when datagridview related field is clicked

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have some fields like textbox's and combobox's that show related data when a datagridview line is clicked. Thus every clicked row should present the same values and from related table into that textbox's and combobox's but some does not appear. This happens with the data related (from other table) and even with from the datagridview.

As some field data are right and other not I think that perhaps this is a memory issue. Is there any way to clear and refill those fields? I have try the code below but with no success.

EDITED: 
It seems that every 3 clicks cleans the combobox. But if I clicked a 4th and return to click the one before it reappears. I am puzzled!

EDITED 2: 
It seems this is a known issue by  Microsoft and have no solution.

As posted here: [Winforms combobox loses autocomplete value on lostfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291945/winforms-combobox-loses-autocomplete-value-on-lostfocus)

Even the "3 steps test" relate... unfortunately the link to Microsoft is no longer active. So I have to continue my investigation...
...

```
Private Sub Month_work_ListDataGridView_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Month_work_ListDataGridView.CellClick

Me.AndrosAdapter.Fill(Me.ActivworkxDataSet.Andros)
Me.Month_work_ListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ActivworkxDataSet.Month_work_List)

(... other code tasks ...)

End Sub
```

Comment: From the code you have shown you are appending all of the data to the table every time you click a cell. That is a very poor idea. Also your question concerns binding and you have shown nothing of the sort

Comment: Do you use something like this anywhere?

ComboBox1.DataSource = BindingSource
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = “Name”
ComboBox1.ValueMember = “ID”

Comment: @Mr. Tripodi - You have absolutely right... that was a very bad idea. Is there something I may do now to workaround that issue... clean before reload data? Thankyou.   @Devcon - Yes. I have it in the VS DesignMode (ComboBox Tasks) like this: `ComboBox1.DataSource = AndrosDataSource ComboBox1.DisplayMember = “Name” ComboBox1.ValueMember = “Name”... as also SelectedValue=Month_work_ListDataSource. Is this the issue? Thank you.

Comment: @JosédeMatos What I believe you must do is watch some tutorials on databinding and data access through ADO.Net I do not have time to provide such lesson

Comment: @Mr. Tripodi I certainly watch them in the future. Unfortunately I can't go back now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug confirmed.

A supposed Hotfix was here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2868238/a-combo-box-control-selects-an-unexpected-value-in-windows-7-sp-1-or-windows-server-2008-r2

but is no logger available: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4343220/this-hotfix-is-no-longer-available

Instead Microsoft suggests to upgrade to Windows 10.

I solve it with a workaround:

```
Me.CBoxObra.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

Where before was:

```
Me.CBoxObra.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
```

And the problem no longer appears.