# Winforms comboBox binding not working unless I press enter

Tags: winforms, combobox, binding

I have a Winforms form with a combobox that has its Text bound to a string property P1 on the form.

When I run the app, select an item from the dropdown list of the combobox and then press Tab (without pressing Enter first), the combobox's SelectedIndex has changed, but P1 is still blank.

But if I press Enter in the combobox after selecting an item from the dropdown list before tabbing out of it, then P1 is set correctly.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work without having to press enter after selecting an item from the dropdown list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the AutoCompleteMode to SuggestAppend or Append and then set AutoCompleteSource = ListItems, that should fix your issue.

[Combobox Autocomplete Tab-out does not select item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268521/combobox-autocomplete-tab-out-does-not-select-item)